# Add shadow to image using opencv python for augmented reality

Tags: python, opencv, augmented-reality

I have been assigned to augmented reality based on opencv python.

---

**Project description:**
Need to take an interior room image,Paint that interior with our own colour.

---

**Proceeded:**
I have taken an image and made the colouring in that with the use of edge based method,floodfill.

---

**Issue:**
Now what is the issue is to give the liveness of image.In my point liveness is the shadow.if i colouring some area its getting coloured but the the colour is fitted over the shadow

---

**Requirement:**
Now i need to add the original shadow to the image after colouring.
Here i have attached the original image and coloured image for reference[Result image]

Comment: Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to apply a full black image with a low alpha value.

Realized that OpenCV has not good solutions for that, but you can use Pillow.

http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2013/11/transparency-with-pil/